# How to render Resonse in FlatList with Axios React Native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I used Axios to fetch this API , and I face a problem, how to render the response in Flatlist ?

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function App() {
  Axios({
    method: "GET",
    baseURL:
      "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/kamalo11/9nab7z/2ab26f49667b945a4e78679492fc7950bc1df3be/files/ecommerce.json",
  })
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    
  const res = res;

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={res}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.price}</Text>}
    />
  );
}
```

What's the souloution?

Comment: `const res = res;` you can't assign here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  Axios({
    .....
    .then((res) => setData(res)) // update state here
    ...
    

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data} // change here
      ....
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first set the res in state

> `this.setState({res: res});`

then call state in FlatList

```
 <FlatList
      data={this.state.res}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.price}</Text>}
    />
```